# iphone local database synchronization with remote server master

Tags: iphone, database

I've tried googling this with very few helpful answers....basically I have a master database sitting on a linux server with a partial local copy sitting on the iphone.  The database gets updated a few times every minute and I would like to somehow transnit (push, pull, or poll) the changes in real time to anyone using the app on the iphone.....is there a standard way of accomplishing this?  Is it easier done with mysql over sqlite3 for example?  Are there any open source frameworks?  Or do I have to roll my own?

Answer (score 0):

The "standard" way is probably using CoreData — I'd be surprised if it didn't have change-tracking features (but I haven't looked at it too hard).

The real problem is figuring out how to diff a database. To do this generically, your database needs "revisions", and then it's not really a normal database anymore.

Comment: I would recommend against using `CoreData` to mirror a remote database.  Stick with `sqlite` if bulk operations like these are core to your app, particularly if the original database is also SQL.

Comment: Justin, the problem is what is the most effective way in real-time to do the syncing?

Comment: How do you plan on handling conflicts?